# PHP Alternating Content

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I am trying to make a template where:

```
if(no_feature == 1) {

   TEXT (displayed on the left side), IMAGE (displayed on the right side)
} else {
   IMAGE (displayed on the left side), TEXT (displayed on the right side)
}
```

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <?php if ($this->get_field('no_feature')== 1);?>
    <div class="one_half">
        <?php echo "TEXT";?>
    </div>
    <div class="one_half last">
        <?php echo "Image";?>
    </div>
    <?php else:?>
    <div class="one_half">
        <?php echo "Image";?>
    </div>
    <div class="one_half last">
        <?php echo "Text";?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: Your `if()` clause is empty. Is that your question?

Comment: How do I create a template where user inputs 

- no_feature

Then it will read whether to print Image on the left/right.

Answer (score 0):

You this code:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <?php if ($this->get_field('no_feature')== 1): ?>
    <div class="one_half">
        <?php echo "TEXT";?>
    </div>
    <div class="one_half last">
        <?php echo "Image";?>
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div class="one_half">
        <?php echo "Image";?>
    </div>
    <div class="one_half last">
        <?php echo "Text";?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

In the if condition you have the semicolumn that should be **:** mark.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually better not to implement such things as variants in the HTML DOM tree. Instead make a clean list and handle the visualization by using style classes (using float rules in this case). This way you separate the content from the visualization which means: you can change the visualization later without having to reprogram everything everytime.